# #pragma managed

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

Что означает следующая строка???
`#pragma managed(push, off)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это нужно при компиляции исходников на C++/CLI.

C++/CLI — это .NET-расширение языка C++. При выполнении кода C++/CLI участвуют две рантайм-библиотеки: нативная и управляемая. Некоторые правила для этих рантайм-библиотек отличаются (например, время создания статических объектов). Обычно функции компилируются в CLR-режиме, но вы можете явно указать нативный, совместимый со стандартом C++ режим, используя `#pragma managed`.

При компиляции в нативном режиме эта функция «общается» с нативным рантаймом, а при компиляции в управляемом — в управляемом. В частности, нативная функция не может использовать управляемые типы (к примеру, `System::String^`).
`#pragma managed(push, off)` собственно означает «запомнить текущее состояние в стеке состояний, и установить нативный режим». В конце нативного участка обычно следует `#pragma managed(pop)`, что восстанавливает предыдущее состояние из стека.

По поводу языковых различий управляемом и неуправляемом режимах, [в документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/reference/clr-restrictions) есть полный список. В частности, не работает inline assembler и `vprintf`.

Также, управляемые функции могут быть обнаружены в модуле при помощи рефлексии, в отличие от нативных.

---

Подключать стандартные заголовочные файлы лучше, понятно, в нативном режиме, раз соответствующие библиотеки были скомпилированы тоже в нативном режиме.

Comment: А чем отличаются нативный и CLR режимы и для чего из одного переходить в другой?

Comment: @user251082: Дописал в ответе.

Comment: нативный это компиляция в машинный код конкретного процессора, а managed в код виртуальной машины (например .net или Dalvik). Машинный код раза в два эффективнее, но непереносим на другие CPU

Comment: @PavelGridin: Не думаю, что всё так просто. Адресная арифметика и `reinterpret_cast` вряд ли могут быть выражены в MSIL.